# Ax 2012 X++ Report Controller class caching

Tags: axapta, ssrs-2012, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

***Short Version :***

If an error is thrown during the execution of an SSRS report after the associated RDP temporary tables have been updated, the next time the report is run for the same parameters, code execution does not insert fresh data into said tables. Any idea why and how to prevent it?

***Long Version :***

I am trying to modify the run conditions of a standard report (`SalesInvoiceReport`) so that the original of any invoice can only be printed once. For all reprints, the "Copy preview" option should be used.

For the most part, the customization is working as intended. I used the `CustInvoiceJour.PrintedOriginals` field and the `CustInvoiceJour.updatePrintedOriginals()` (both part of Standard Ax) to maintain the number of originals that have been printed and a slight modification to the `SalesInvoiceController.outputReport()` method throw an error of an original is being re-printed. Below is the code added to achieve this :

```
...
    //  <A147> Code to disable reprints if an original is already printed
    isOriginalPrintable = CustInvoiceJour::findRecId(custInvoiceJour.RecId).PrintedOriginals == 0;
    srsPrintDestinationSettings = formLetterReport.getCurrentPrintSetting().parmPrintJobSettings();
    //srsPrintMediumType          = srsPrintDestinationSettings.printMediumType();
    if ((printCopyOriginal == PrintCopyOriginal::Original || printCopyOriginal == PrintCopyOriginal::OriginalPrint))
    {
        // If no originals printed, allow prints.
        //      Need to re-read the CustInvoiceJour record from the table to get updated data
        //      If the Original is printed but the prin form is not refreshed, the form's recordset does not update to the latest data.
        if(isOriginalPrintable)
        {
            CustInvoiceJour::updatePrinted(custInvoiceJour, (srsPrintDestinationSettings.numberOfCopies() == 0 ? 1 : srsPrintDestinationSettings.numberOfCopies()));
        }
        // Don't allow the original document to be printed more than once.
        else
        {
            error(strFmt("@GLS223085", custInvoiceJour.InvoiceId, custInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate));
            return;
        }
    }
    //  </A147>
...
```

I placed this in the `SalesInvoiceContreller.outputReport()` because I found similar code present there as part of standard Ax, albeit for use in specific country regions.

When user uses the **Original Preview** button, the error is thrown and code execution stops but the RDP temporary tables used to hold the report data have already been updated with report data (specifically the field which hold the Report title is set to **Invoice**).

When the user reruns the report, this time with the **Copy Preview** button, code execution somehow skips inserting fresh data into the temp tables (which would set the Report Title field to **Invoice Copy**) and the first *copy* output still says **Invoice**, defeating the requirement.

Comment: Same question in AX Community: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/198204/509985

Comment: Have you tried using `throw error(...)` instead of `error(...)`? And removing the `return;` line as it wouldn't be necessary if you throw an error.